# Taskbar height/width on the side

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I have my taskbar at the left side but I hate its width. I don't know why the icons (Wi-Fi connection, Volume etc.) are in two columns. That expands the width of my taskbar.

[image]

I tried to unlock the taskbar and change its width manually; it didn't help. When I change the position of my taskbar to default (bottom), everything is nice in one line.